# Word/expression request & expression explanation

Tags: phrase-requests

First: What's the term for someone who lives a very simple life with just enough to survive on?

Second: What's the meaning of the expression "a life of roots"?

Comment: Please divide these up into two questions. Edit the title to reflect the actual question. You should also show some research effort, particularly for the second one. Meanwhile, welcome to English Language & Usage! Please take the [tour] to find how this site operates.

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the two separate questions–tsk, and I was hoping you were going to ask about feeding two birds with a bagel...or was it a scone?

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what single question (which is all it should be) you're trying to ask here. You've asked two questions—and the title you used is additionally confusing. (What do two birds have to do with anything?)

Comment: mkennedy Sir, I believe this site is a great medium for research. And for the second question, my research findings are not satisfactory. That's why I posted it here. The questions though, have been edited for clarity. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To answer what I assume is the main question, A person who lives their life as simple as possible utilizing the bare minimum to survive upon is most likely an **Ascetic**.

Similar to monks, Ascetics practice a form of abstinence from indulgences, meaning that they don't have any kind of luxuries in their lives to indulge themselves upon outside of their chosen way of life.

Comment: Ascetic fits my description. Really appreciate.